# Mostrar Alert o mensaje despues de un header? PHP

Tags: php

estaba creando un `insert`, y al enviar los datos me aparecía un mensaje de alerta que decía que los datos se habían insertado con éxito, pero ahora, la pagina se queda en blanco y solo muestra esa alerta.

Lo que hice para que no se quedara pegada fue redireccionar otra vez con `header`, solo que esta vez no me sale el mensaje o la alerta.

Es muy simple supongo, lo puse antes y después del `header` y no funciono.

```
if ($mail->send()) 
{

  header("location:controlador.php");

  echo '<p class="alert alert-success agileits" role="alert">Captura realizada correctamente!p>';

  } else {

  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para imprimir un alert dentro de php hazlo de esta maneara:

```
<?php 
     echo "<script>
                alert('Mensaje');
                window.location= 'url.php'
    </script>";
?>
```

Comment: Funciono muchas gracias!!

Comment: me ayudo esta respuesta gracias

Answer (score 2):

Usando `PHP` y el método [`header`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php), podrías resolverlo así:

```
if ($mail->send()) {

  // Recargar la página despues de 10 segundos y redireccionar a "controlador.php"
  header('Refresh: 10; URL=controlador.php');

  echo '<p class="alert alert-success agileits" role="alert">Captura realizada correctamente!p>';
} else {

  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

> Recuerde que **header()** debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>alert('Loading...(Cargando)');</script>
```

Comment: Hola, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser bien recibidas por la comunidad. Deberías editar tu respuesta para añadir más detalles (p.e. ¿qué es lo que hace el código? ¿cómo soluciona el problema?) y explica cuál es la diferencia entre tu respuesta y otras respuestas anteriores. Completa el [tour] para más información.